# Rest API Object doesn't accept SDT param?

Tags: genexus

Im coding a **Rest API** and I had to migrate my gx16 project to gx17 then i can use the **&RestCode** variable to change de *HTTP Status*.

When I use **PRCRest**, it's receives a SDT in parameters with *no problems*. ✔

So, here is the thing:
I have to be able to receive the following request:

```
{
    "identificacao" : {
        "inscricao_imovel":"0123"
    },
    "dimensao":"A4"
}
```

When i updated to **API Object** i get the following error when ***building***.

```
api_poupatempo_services_rest.java:50: error: variable AV7identificacao might not have been initialized
      AV7identificacao.fromJSonString(gxep_obtercertidaonegativaimovel__postparm.identificacao, null);
```

My SDT is OK because when i receive then thrown a **PRCRest** i can read it. The issue is the **PRCRest** CAN'T change de http status and send a response body , but with the **API Object** i can change http status and send body response easily.

Here is my API Object:

```
Routes{ 

    [RestMethod(POST)]
    obterCertidaoNegativaImovel(in:&identificacao, in:&dimensao, out:&pdf, out:&codigo, out:&mensagem)
        => api.poupatempo.obterCertidaoNegativaImovel(&identificacao, &dimensao, &pdf, &codigo, &mensagem); 
    
}
```

Here is the SDT:
[sdtidentificacao](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARG3a.png)

Gx17u3-Java.

Thanks.

Comment: There have been several improvements in the API object in the latest versions. Did you try with GeneXus 17 upgrade 6, or with the preview channel version (to be released as GeneXus 17 upgrade 7)?

Comment: I have updated to genexus 17 u6 and it is now working fine. Thanks for your tips.